# SQL: How to replace one with two?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, replace, line

I have a table "first":

[image]

I am trying to write a query.

```
    If first.type = 'MM'

    then replace this line in two new lines

    where first.type = 'HH' and first.type = 'VV'.
```

For example : The line where first.type = 'MM':

[image]

I want to replace this line like that:

[image]

And the result:

[image]

Does someone have an idea on how this can be done?

I'm using MS SQL Server Management Studio Express.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select id,freq,parity,line,type,gain,obdim from [first] where type<>'MM'
union
select id,freq,parity,line,'HH' as type,gain,obdim from [first] where type='MM'
union
select id,freq,parity,line,'VV' as type,gain,obdim from [first] where type='MM'
```

Comment: +1 but please expand the * into the actual columns.  Soon as this table gets updated everything falls apart.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id,frequency, 'VV' type --, .. 
from table1
where type='MM'
union all
select id,frequency, 'HH' as type --, .. 
from table1
where type='MM'
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is probably very specific in the sense that it implies that the `type` column can only have values `HH`, `MM`, or `VV`.

```
SELECT
  f.ID,
  f.freq,
  f.parity,
  f.line,
  t.type,
  f.gain,
  f.obdim
FROM [first] f
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 'HH' AS type
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'VV'
  ) t ON f.type IN (t.type, 'MM')
```

Comment: @Juronis: Not sure why there should be such an error. I've changed it slightly, though, should now be no problem. Also thanks to your comment I noticed a mistake in my solution. Fixed it as well.

Comment: hmmmm, still don't work. I get the error "query input must contain at least one table or query"..

Comment: What RDBMS are you trying this solution in? Is it MS SQL Server or MS Access?

Comment: MS SQL Server, but this example I run in MS Access. I will try in MS SQL Server.